# geom_col over year and groups: any way to avoid demarcations in the bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data on U.S. border apprehensions ([USA data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/40cybumjnfnivlc/data_usa.csv?dl=0)) and I want to plot a `geom_col` of those apprehensions. I do not care about counts of individual countries, just some region of interests (Mexico, Hond/Guatemala/El Salvador and Rest of World).

After downloading the data, I read it in R and use:

```
graph_usa <- 
  ggplot(data = app_usa, aes(x = year, y = apprehensions, group = region_of_interest)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = region_of_interest), alpha = 0.8) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Apprehensions: United States") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c(2007, 2010, 2013, 2016, 2019)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(rgb(0.9, 0.5, 0.1), rgb(0.2, 0.5, 0.7), rgb(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))) +
  labs(fill="Region of Interest") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.5, 0.8))
```

What happens is that there are some annoying horizontal bars that denote country divisions within the region. So for example, the oj bar has no divisions because its just one country; the blue one has two, because it represents three countries. The gray ones represent a lot of countries.

**One obvious solution would be to aggregate the dataset into these three regions**, but I'm wondering if geom_col doesn't have an implicit command that aggregates instead.

Thanks!

[image: Geom_col output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate data in bar charts by using `geom_bar(stat = ...)`. `geom_col()` is just the convenience function for `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`. Setting `stat = "summary"` and `fun = sum` will sum the data per group, thereby avoiding the demarcations.

```r
library(ggplot2)

app_usa <- read.csv(choose.files(), header = TRUE)

ggplot(data = app_usa, aes(x = year, y = apprehensions, group = region_of_interest)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = region_of_interest), alpha = 0.8,
           fun = sum, stat = "summary") +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Apprehensions: United States") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(rgb(0.9, 0.5, 0.1), rgb(0.2, 0.5, 0.7), rgb(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))) +
  labs(fill="Region of Interest") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.5, 0.8))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

The issue (lines in the bars of **pdf** output) occur when using `alpha=0.8`.

While I can't explain why but it disappears after removing `alpha` or using `alpha=1`

This is the pdf output:

[image]

**First answer:**
The dataframe is called `df` here.

1. Change `group` to `fill` in `aes`
2. remove `fill` from `geom_col` and add `position="stack"`
3. Use `factor` in `scale_x_discrete`

```
graph_usa <- 
    ggplot(data = df, aes(x = year, y = apprehensions, fill = region_of_interest)) +
    geom_col(position = "stack", alpha = 0.8) +
    xlab("") +
    ylab("Apprehensions: United States") +
    scale_x_discrete(limits = factor(c(2007, 2010, 2013, 2016, 2019))) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c(rgb(0.9, 0.5, 0.1), rgb(0.2, 0.5, 0.7), rgb(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))) +
    labs(fill="Region of Interest") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.position = c(0.5, 0.8))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi TarJae, this doesn't seem to have worked. In the R output, it looks solved, but when I save it to pdf, it still displays those lines. Also, using "factor" kinda messes the whole axis, but that's another problem.

Comment: how do you convert it to pdf?

Comment: This is strange after saving it to pdf with `ggsave` no plots are show in my Plots window. As you can see it worked without problems before!

Comment: ggsave(destination, plot = graph_usa)

Comment: yes on the plot windows it looks great, but after ggsave the lines appear.

Comment: hmmmh. Strange... I will have a look.

Comment: Please see my update. I did multiple try and error. Finally I think I got the answer. The lines in the pdf output occur when using alpha < 1. I can't explain why. But your issue should be solved now.